# Is it Possible to independently scale each axis of a mesh?

Tags: scaling

I have a model of a shoehorn that is quite large.  I would like to make a travel size by scaling the X & Y axes by 66.7% and the Z axis by 80% in order to make it wider than is achieved by uniform scaling.  Is there a way to do this in MeshLab?  I am brand new user of MeshLab operating on a Linux (Ubuntu) laptop with AMD processor and video.

I looked through all the menus and the documentation I can find and did not find this addressed.  I am expecting that a powerful sophisticated tool like MeshLab will permit independent axis scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in Meshlab-EduTech Wiki as follows:
Filters > Normals, Curvatures and Orientations > Tranform: Scale
In the dialog box, independent values can be input for each axis.